# Batch request using Retrofit

Tags: android, http, url, networking, retrofit

I'd like to perform batch request using Retrofit. It there any nice way, how to achieve it? Basically what I'm trying to do is to replace some characters in query part of URL (replace block is allowed only in path part of URL - using `@Path` annotation).

Here is a pseudocode for my problem.

```
@GET("/v2/multi?requests=/users/self,/venues/search?client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&v={v}&ll={ll}&intent={intent}&limit={limit}")
    ProfileSearchVenuesResponse searchVenuesAndProfiles(@ReplaceBy("client_id") String clientId,
                          @ReplaceBy("client_secret") String clientSecret,
                          @ReplaceBy("v") int version,
                          @ReplaceBy("ll") String location,
                          @ReplaceBy("intent") String intent,
                          @ReplaceBy("limit") int limit);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`@Query`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/index.html?retrofit/http/Query.html) is what you are looking for:

```
@GET("/v2/multi?requests=/users/self,/venues/search")
ProfileSearchVenuesResponse searchVenuesAndProfiles(
    @Query("client_id") String clientId,
    @Query("client_secret") String clientSecret,
    @Query("v") int version,
    @Query("ll") String location,
    @Query("intent") String intent,
    @Query("limit") int limit);
```

In version 1.7.0 of Retrofit (released yesterday) the exception message for attempting to use `@Path` in the original question instructs you as to the right solution:

> URL query string "client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&v={v}&ll={ll}&intent={intent}&limit={limit}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

Comment: Thanks! I was on 1.6.0, so I didn't get info that I can use `@Query` for it.